# insert data in multiple mysql table with graphql nodejs

Tags: node.js, graphql

I am building a nodeJs app with GraphQl, I want when a user sends data to a server, it will insert some of the data in users table and then get the last inserted id and use it to insert the rest data in company table in MySQL DB, Am using GraphQl

like for example when a user submits the following data like (username, email, companyName, companyType), it will insert the username, email in the user's table and then get the id of that user and insert it in usersId in company table with the rest of the data (companyName, companyType)
hope this is clear enough

Here is my code

```
const graphql = require('graphql')
const Rcompany = require('../models/company')
const RUsers = require('../models/users')

const {
    GraphQLObjectType, 
    GraphQLString, 
    GraphQLSchema,
    GraphQLID,
    GraphQLInt, 
    GraphQLNonNull,
    GraphQLList
} = graphql

const CompanysType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'company',
    fields:()=>({
        id: {type: GraphQLID},
        companyName: {type: GraphQLString},
        companyType: {type: GraphQLString},
        usersId: {type: GraphQLString},
        user: {
            type: UserType,
            resolve(parent, args){
                return RUsers.findById(parent.companyName)
            }
        }
    })
})

const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'user',
    fields:()=>({
        id: {type: GraphQLID},
        username: {type: GraphQLString},
        email: {type: GraphQLString},
        posts:{
            type: CompanysType,
            resolve(parent, args){
                return RUsers.findById(parent.id)
            }
        }
    })
})

const Mutation = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Mutation',
    fields:{ 
        addPost:{
            type:UserType,
            args:{                
                username:{type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)},
                email:{type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)}
            },
            resolve(parent, args){
                let hUsers = new RUsers({
                    username: args.username,
                    email:args.email
                })
                return hUsers.save().then((data) => {
                    // here is where i dont know how to proceed
                })
            }
        }
    }
})

module.exports = new GraphQLSchema({
    mutation:Mutation
})
```

please suggest me how can i proceed with this?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout async module for nodejs. It has a waterfall method. You can perform steps in sequence with waterfall and the good thing about this is it allows you to pass on results to next step from previous step. This is what will solve your problem.
e.g

```
async.waterfall([
  function firstStep(done) {},
  function secondStep(previousResult, done) {}
],
function (err) {});
```